# Where can I download a trial version of Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, ios

I'm planning to install OS X as a guest OS on a PC to do iOS development. But I can't find a place to download the trial version of OS X. Is it not available?

Comment: You cannot install OS X on a "PC" it can only be installed on a Apple computer.  Any discussion on "hacking" OS X is likely not on topic for Super User furthermore strictly against the license for OS X.

Comment: @Ramhound, My intent was to find out is it possible to use a single PC to do both windows and mac development work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a trial version for Mac OS X. Recent versions are less than $30 anyway.

Also, installing OS X as a VM on a non-Apple computer would violate the EULA:

> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software.

Your PC is not "a Mac computer running the Apple software".

Comment: It's such a pity that Apple locks down their software.

Comment: @agweber: Apple isn't primarily a software company; they're primarily a hardware company that also happens to provide software to support that hardware. From their point of view, OS X exists primarily to get people to buy Macs, so selling it to run on PCs would be counter-productive. It'd also be a support nightmare for them, since they'd have to deal with all the various PC hardware (drivers, etc) instead of just the few hardware configs they sell.